# direct sum of modules and matrix ring

Tags: ring-theory, direct-sum

I have $M$ a left module over $R$. I take $M^{(n)}$ the direct sum of $n$ copies of $M$. Then $A := _R\text{End}(M^{(n)})$ is exactly the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $E:= _R\text{End}(M)$.

Why is this true?

It is clear that given a matrice, it is in $A$ but why, given $f\in E$ is it necessarily a matrice?

Comment: Isn't it a bit silly to use a mapping between nouns and their plurals that isn't one-to-one?

Comment: Given a map from $f:M^n\to M^n$, an "obvious" way to break it up into pieces is to do $f_{ij}:M_i\to M_j$ given by projections. But you could also do $f_{ij}:M_j\to M_i$. I forget which way is the correct way, but after you pick the right one, everything works out with matrix multiplication.